# How can I change the position of Joomla's articles?

Tags: html, css, joomla, joomla-article

How can I change the position I want an article to be? The default is the center, just like a blog.

I tried to use the modules:

-Articles as Module

-Articles Anywhere

but i didn't have any success.

Comment: where do you want to change the position to exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question sounds like you don't know Joomla that well, or you need to explain a little more.

Because your question leaves us with a thousand answers.

To move text to the right with html you can use inline style tag to float your text like this:

```
<p style="float:right;">your text</p>
```

or you can use CSS styles like this

```
<style type="text/css">
.classname {
 float:left;
}
</style>
<p class="classname">your text</p>
```

To move modules around in Joomla take a look at this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yn-_Hyf-zj0&noredirect=1)

But I am not sure if this is what you are asking.